# XtraReport display property as list (Forms app)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, list, devexpress, report

I'm trying to display every object inside a list which is a property of another object. Since my structure is very complex, I will demonstrate with a simple example:

An author has a property list of his books, but report should show every author and every book.

I'm unable to show every book, instead the report just shows an author and only his first book, and not other ones.

The platform is C# for desktop forms, using Entity Framework.

Comment: You need to set the data source as a List of Authors, and each author need to have the list of books, in the design mode you need to pay attention where how you display the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this - [Master-Detail Report using custom DataSource ( ArrayList)](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q443463)

> Take a look at the [A Good Example for Runtime Creation of Detailed
>   Reports with Subreports which utilizes generic List as
>   datasource](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q439739.aspx) report that demonstrates how to create a master-detail
>   report dynamically using a list of object.

References:
[How to show nested list in report?](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q323503)
[How to: Bind a Report to a Collection that Implements the ITypedList Interface](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument4046)

Hope this help..

Comment: It did helped, thanks.
BTW, I created new class designed specially for this report (something like ViewModel) and it's another way to do it. Thanks anyway for your time